# Creating Mobile Sub Navigation Menu Dropdown with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, navigation

I am trying to create a mobile friendly view of the navigation on a website I've created. I'd like to have a dropdown (down arrow) icon next to li's that have the "haschildMobile" class with the items in the "mobileSubLevel" class hidden. Then when people click on the "haschildMobile" item, the dropdown items in "mobileSubLevel" show.

I've tried several different ways to use CSS and jQuery to solve this (including the code included in this post), but to no avail. Any ideas?

```js
$(function(){
    $('.haschildMobile').click(function() {
      $(this).('.mobileSubLevel').toggle();
    $('.mobileSubLevel').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.mobileSubLevel').hide();
    });
})
```

```css
#dnnMobileMenu .mobileTopLevel { 
position: relative; 
height: auto; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}
#dnnMobileMenu .mobileTopLevel li a {
display: inline-block;
color: #999;
font-size: 13px;
}
#dnnMobileMenu .mobileTopLevel li a span { 
display: inline-block; 
height: 42px; 
line-height: 42px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 15px; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
}
#dnnMobileMenu .mobileTopLevel li { 
position: relative; 
list-style-type: none; 
float: none; 
width: 100%; 
border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1; 
}
li.haschildMobile:after { 
padding-left: 4px; 
content: ' v'; 
}
#dnnMobileMenu .mobileSubLevel li { 
display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="dnnMobileMenu">
<ul class="mobileTopLevel">

<li class="itemMobile firstMobile breadcrumbMobile selectedMobile">

<a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>

</li>

<li class="itemMobile haschildMobile">

<a href="#"><span>Dropdown Area</span></a>

<div class="mobileSubLevel">
<ul>

<li class="itemMobile firstMobile">

<a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a>

</li>

 <li class="itemMobile">

<a href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>

</li>

<li class="itemMobile">

<a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing a chunk of HTML from before what you have pasted in. Can you include more CSS too for your menu layout?

Comment: @bbodien Thanks for pointing that out. I've added more of the mobile menu CSS from my website.